# How do I add a checkmark to my-sites save settings hook

Tags: filters, hooks, blog

I want to add a checkmark to the `my-sites.php` through a hook and then press save settings and have it do a function that executes a SQL query.

I've added the checkmark but I don't know how to go further now, I've read about hooks in forms and everything but what I put into `my-sites.php` is already in a form so my guess is I should be able to use the submit action of that form?

```
//Adds checkmarks to the my-sites.php interface My Websites.
function makeLiableCheckMark($links) {
  ..wp_enqueue's....

  global $user_blog; 
  global $wpdb;
  $blog_id = $user_blog->userblog_id;

  $sitemetaRowExists = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."sitemeta WHERE site_id=%d AND meta_key=%s",$blog_id,'aansprakelijk_voor_facturatie'));
  if($sitemetaRowExists > 0) {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="liable_id" value="disable" checked> blabla.<br>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="liable_id" value="enable"> blabla';
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind making an [edit] to include your code?

Comment: Code added, it's just adding a checkbox in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though have altered the page to submit your data. Assuming that that code work properly:

1. [`my-sites.php` loads `admin.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/my-sites.php)

   ```
   10  require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );
   ```
2. [Which fires the `load-{pagenow}` hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/admin.php)

   ```
   330         /**
   331          * Fires before a particular screen is loaded.
   332          *
   333          * The load-* hook fires in a number of contexts. This hook is for core screens.
   334          *
   335          * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$pagenow`, is a global variable
   336          * referring to the filename of the current page, such as 'admin.php',
   337          * 'post-new.php' etc. A complete hook for the latter would be
   338          * 'load-post-new.php'.
   339          *
   340          * @since 2.1.0
   341          */
   342         do_action( 'load-' . $pagenow );
   ```

That is probably the hook you need, but based on the very generic information you've provided it is hard to write much code.

Comment: I added some code of what I am trying to do.